# WebElement not identified

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify the element but no matter which search strategy i use,it still throws an exception element not found
I am not sure if it is because of hidden javascript.
Please help me in identifying the element with name QuotationIDText

Below is the code

```
<table onmousedown="javascript:hide();" id="Table5" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="frmArea" style="WIDTH: 527px" width="527">
                        <table class="frmcontbl" id="Table6" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="WIDTH: 203px; HEIGHT: 28px">
                                    <span id="QuotationIDLabel" class="fieldheader" align="left">Quotation ID:</span><br>
                                    <input name="QuotationIDText" type="text" id="QuotationIDText" class="input wildcard" style="WIDTH: 195px" tabindex="1" maxlength="50" size="22" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the element inside `frame`, did you try wait?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='QuotationIDText']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: You haven't provided a link to the webpage, nor code you've attempted, so I'll just have to guess what's wrong with it.*

**Firstly, determine if your table is not loading asynchronously.**

To test it, try running the page without JavaScript. Open Chrome or any browser you use, and disable JavaScript. If it doesn't load without JavaScript, try using [Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

If it does load without JavaScript, try **copying XPath**.

To do this on Chrome, right click on an element you want, and click "**Inspect Element**". Then, right click on the element you want, go to "**Copy >**", and select "**Copy XPath**". Then use the XPath like in the @Vikrant's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about your issue.
But if you think element is not found because some js code running is not complete you can use some sort of waiting.

The most accurate option is to use something like that:

```
public void WaitForPageLoaded(IWebDriver webDriver)
{
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Timeout);
   wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
   wait.Until(JQueryIsLoaded());
   wait.Until(DomIsReady());
}

protected Func<IWebDriver, bool> JQueryIsLoaded()
   {
      return webDriver =>
      {
         try
         {
            return EvalScript<long>(webDriver, "return jQuery.active").Equals(0);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            return true;
         }
    };
}

protected Func<IWebDriver, bool> DomIsReady()
{
   return webDriver => EvalScript<string>(webDriver, "return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
}
```

The simple way to wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
return wait.Until(driver => searchContext.FindElement(selector));
```